# Can I validate the results of my package with that of any tutorial or workshop?

Tags: research-process, peer-review, bioinformatics, software-papers

I have developed a software package for the analysis of genomic data, in which, I have implemented a variety of functions like normalization, clustering etc (from already available tools i.e., clubbed them together) in one software package with a different working framework.
I am now trying to validate the result produced, after analysis of some dataset, using my developed/proposed software tool.
What is the best way to validate/verify these results? and If I am replicating the results of an online tutorial, does that qualify to be called a valid verification?

Comment: Frankly, I am too stupid to understand this question.

Comment: I am sorry for the ambiguity in my question. I have reframed it and I hope it makes sense now.

Comment: I would expect that the data used in an online tutorial was chosen to enable lessons to be taught. As such, it might be biased in various ways. In that case, your results probably wouldn't be valid. It is the quality of the data, not its source that is important.

Comment: I'm on the fence about close voting as domain-specific, but I don't think the fact that this is genetics software matters very much. I'm not going to CV for now, but  maybe genericizing the Q might help you avoid closure.

Answer (score 3):

You want to know if your software works correctly. One way to do that is to compare the results from your software with "known to be true" results. This begs the question: how do I get these magical "known to be true" results, and you think maybe from an online tutorial. This depends on the quality and trustworthiness of that tutorial, and the variance is huge. So in general, the answer is no, no, no, no, run away, don't look back, forget about it, just don't do it (you get the point by now). However, there may be very trustworthy tutorials out there where this might work. But if you know that is the case, then that is because you can derive and prove the results presented in the tutorial yourself, so you don't need the tutorial anymore. So that is a bit of a catch 22.

In general "known to be true" results are special cases with a known answer. In addition (but more dangerous) you can compare your results with results from trusted and known to be high quality software. Problem is that even high quality software is still written by humans and humans do make errors. Those errors aren't random. You may well be replicating each other's bugs...

I assume you have broken up the problem in lots and lots of sub-routines. (if that is not the case, then that is something you need to fix) A good place to start is to create unit tests for each and every sub-routine.

Comment: Those benchmark "known to be true" results can be found from papers and standard textbooks too, right?

Comment: +1 just for being fun to read. But also accurate.

Comment: @justauser papers and textbooks suffer from the same problems as using trusted and high quality software. In fact, those papers and textbooks probably used that that high quality software to get their results.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, as mentioned, I am reproducing the modules of the different software in one. I guess, it should be OK to use the analytical results of a given dataset in those software(which I have replicated), to verify the results obtained from my software. And the tutorials which I am talking about are trustworthy as they are the "how to use vignettes" of the software I am reproducing.

Comment: That does not sound anywhere near good enough for your purpose. This way you are pretty much guaranteed to reproduce the bugs in the other software. You need real known to be true results, results where there is hard analytical proof that it is true.

Comment: @MaartenBuis Sometimes it's essentially not possible. I've been in the exact same situation as OP and aside from a few results on well-known datasets (and possibly reproducing bugs in other software!) you're kind of on your own. If there are discrepancies, it is possible they are due to bugs in the original software; in this case it could sometimes mean worldwide research on the topic for some 20 years or so. All you can do is "independent implementation" and run tests on synthetic data sets in some cases where the analytical answer is clear. Even then it can be hard (think deep learning).